# Creating micrometer histogram with min value as 0.01 and max value as 1

Tags: histogram, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to create a micrometer histogram with min value as 0.1 and max value as 1 and with 10 buckets. I tried to configure the above properties using below config but it is not giving me the buckets less than 1

```
DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
            .percentilesHistogram(true)
            .sla(Duration.ofMillis(50).toNanos(),
                    Duration.ofMillis(100).toNanos(),
                    Duration.ofMillis(150).toNanos())
            .percentiles(PERCENTILES)
            .percentilePrecision(2)
            .minimumExpectedValue(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1))
            .maximumExpectedValue(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1))
            .build();
```

Any pointers to do this will be greatly appreciated.